# Adding Event Handling to Jframe dialog

Tags: java, sqlite, popup, jframe

So I've got the following code to make a quick pop up box that informs my user that the program has finished running. I want to handle some extra events once the user clicks Ok, specifically I want to close up some drivers and an sql connection. How can I accomplish this?

Here's the code to that makes the jframe

```
javax.swing.JFrame optionFrame = new javax.swing.JFrame();
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(optionFrame, "Tests Complete. Screenshots and Results can be found at C://Features");
     optionFrame.toFront();
     optionFrame.repaint();
     this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it right after you show the dialog, but before `this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));`

Also remove the part:

```
 optionFrame.toFront();
 optionFrame.repaint();
```

this line (the messageDialog popup):

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(optionFrame, "Tests Complete. Screenshots and Results can be found at C://Features");
```

will hold the Thread calling it till user click ok or close on the popup, no need to do anything extra, any code after this line will be executed after the popup will disappear.

based on your example it could be:

```
 ...
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(optionFrame, "Tests Complete. Screenshots and Results can be found at C://Features");
 // do your clean-up work here (probably invoke some clean up service method)
 this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

Comment: can you give an example of how that would be done? Do I need a separate method to do that? Usually events are handled in separate method right?